# Get current style (rm, sf, tt)

Tags: xetex, latex-base

How to print the current style (rm, sf, tt) in a give position of a document?

```latex
\begin{document}

\sffamily

% print current style -> sf

\rmfamily

% print current style -> rm

\ttfamily

% print current style -> tt

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you really want `rm` etc? as latex never has those names even locally.

You can access the current family, `\f@family`

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\sffamily

\f@family

\rmfamily

\f@family

\ttfamily

\f@family


\end{document}
```

pdftex:

[image]

xetex

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't really need "rm". I was just confused with the different namings. So I used the two letters in analogy to `\textsf` and `\texttt`